# How to execute shortcut key commands to Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I'm developing a Visual Studio Extension which require to execute a command using shortcut keys Ctrl + 6, User should be able to execute the command like VS build command (Ctrl + F5). I have used following method but it require to execute the command while text editor is selected. Please advice how to resolve this.

```
<KeyBindings>    
    <KeyBinding guid="CommandSet" id="MyCommand" key1="6" mod1="CONTROL" editor="guidSourceCodeTextEditor" />
  </KeyBindings>

  <Symbols>
    <!-- This is the package guid. -->
    <GuidSymbol name="MyPackage" value="{ccccc-cc-cc-cc-ccccc}" />
    <GuidSymbol name ="guidSourceCodeTextEditor" value="{8b382828-6202-11d1-8870-0000f87579d2}" />

    <!-- This is the guid used to group the menu commands together -->
    <GuidSymbol name="CommandSet" value="{xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyCommand" value="0x0100" />      
    </GuidSymbol>        
  </Symbols>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
editor="guidSourceCodeTextEditor"
```

I think you need to change it to:

```
editor="guidVSStd97"
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491775.aspx.